# Error with HTML tag for image static resource

Tags: formula-field, static-resources, upload, image-formula

I am getting an HTML tag output instead of the Image in a formula field. The image is stored as Static resource in salesforce. Can someone let me know the possible reason for the error and a way out of it?

Field display HTML Code:

```
Compliance Flag 

<img src="resource/1418040783000/Compliance_Incident" alt="owner" height="20" width="20" border="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how your formula should look like : 
**IF( $User.Id == OwnerId ,IMAGE("/resource/Compliance_Incident", "Owner",20,20),'')**

Hope this helps !

Comment: Not yet solved :(

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the leading /. It's /resource/optional-timestamp/resource-name. Without the leading slash, it's a relative url, which is incorrect for a Visualforce page; it would resolve to /apex/resource/optional-timestamp/resource-name. This results in a 404 error.